# Select multiple folders using Google Picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api, filepicker

I have a native application registered on Google Developers Console and I'm using a Web Application (AngularJS) to get permission from users.

Initially i get the code, i exchange it (on the server) for an auth_token & refresh_token and i try to use the google picker to let the user select folders form his GDrive account.

I can display a simple file picker but the problem is that i can't set up the PickerBuiler so the user could select multiple folders.
Here is what I tried:

```
var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
    .setIncludeFolders(true)
    .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
    .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);


var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
    .addView(docsView)
    .setOAuthToken(response.data.Value)
    .setDeveloperKey('0000000000')
    .build();

picker.setVisible(true);
```

-

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
    addView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS).
    enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
    setOAuthToken(response.data.Value).
    setDeveloperKey('0000000000').
    build();
picker.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: please explain the purpose ?

Comment: `I can't set up` is not a proper problem statement. Please explain more about problems within your attempts

Comment: @charlietfl a bit harsh

Comment: the key is the MULTISELECT_ENABLED which you have. The user needs to ctrl-click on each folder to select multiples. Are you saying that this isn't working, and if not, what is the user seeing instead?

Comment: @pinoyyid and exactly how is asking for clarification being `harsh`? Relax a bit buddy